# Ubuntu 17.04 not booting?

Tags: boot, 17.04

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 17.04 on a separate hard disk from Windows 10 just recently. However, when trying to boot to Ubuntu, it gets stuck on a black screen with some stuff on it. One thing I noticed is the repeating of this line on the screen:

```
MMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck...
```

I didn't get the rest of the message but it gets stuck on this screen indefinitely until I turn off the computer. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look up partitions using a **Live GParted usb** and check for the OS, whether it's been installed properly or not.

Check for the **Boot Flag** in the partition manager when you boot into Live GParted.

It must be set to the partition where your **root** is installed.

Please provide the screenshots so we can go further.

**Update:**
I found something in this [Forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211) which might help you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59368/discussion-on-answer-by-mib-ubuntu-17-04-not-booting).